# Best practises for configuring React Native Backend Url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-elb

What is the best practice to configure backend URL in react native?
Should it be an env variable?
Should it be hard-coded?

The major concern is that we will be using AWS load balancer as the point of entry to our backend. AWS provides arbitrary endpoints like `my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` to hit the load balancer. In the future let's say we want to update the URL for some reason what will be best practice to configure the URL now?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a DNS name like `api.example.com` and hard code that. Then in Route 53 create a A record with the ALIAS endpoint as you mentioned above, but give it a TTL of 1min or so.

In this way you can change your ALIAS endpoint directly in Route 53 and your clients should see the update within 1 minute, without having to make a change to the React native environment.

Comment: Great  kindly accept answer if helpful.